# unable to install dlib on python 3

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, pip, face-recognition, dlib

Im trying to installing dlib on python 3.7 but it always failed

I've installed the cmake and add it to my environment, i've upgraded my pip into the latest version,
but everytime i run

```
pip install dlib
```

It returns **error** as

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xchasbrx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\
    Complete output (74 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 10 2010
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      Failed to run MSBuild command:

        C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe

      to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

        Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.8.3752.0
        [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
        Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

        Build started 2/7/2020 12:37:32 PM.
        Project "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
        C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
        Done Building Project "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

        Build FAILED.

        "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
          C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

            0 Warning(s)
            1 Error(s)

        Time Elapsed 00:00:00.01


      Exit code: 1



    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/Charles/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6wd_c0pw/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\charles\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6wd_c0pw\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xchasbrx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\charles\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

i also **installed** it **by**:

1. go here https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/
2. pick dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz
3. extract it, and go into the folder
4. open command line then run **python setup.py install**

it **returns**:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tools\python\build*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\test'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Charles\Downloads\dlib-19.18.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.18.0\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Charles\Downloads\dlib-19.18.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.18.0\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Charles\Downloads\dlib-19.18.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.18.0\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.8.3752.0
    [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Build started 2/7/2020 12:21:15 PM.
    Project "C:\Users\Charles\Downloads\dlib-19.18.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.18.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    C:\Users\Charles\Downloads\dlib-19.18.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.18.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
    Done Building Project "C:\Users\Charles\Downloads\dlib-19.18.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.18.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

    Build FAILED.

    "C:\Users\Charles\Downloads\dlib-19.18.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.18.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
      C:\Users\Charles\Downloads\dlib-19.18.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.18.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:00.06


  Exit code: 1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Charles/Downloads/dlib-19.18.0.tar/dist/dlib-19.18.0/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 261, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 135, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Charles\\Downloads\\dlib-19.18.0.tar\\dist\\dlib-19.18.0\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Charles\\Downloads\\dlib-19.18.0.tar\\dist\\dlib-19.18.0\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Charles\\Downloads\\dlib-19.18.0.tar\\dist\\dlib-19.18.0\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

i also tried install it from source as :

```
python -m pip install  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/62/aacb236d21fbd08148b1d517d58a9d80ea31bdcd386d26f21f8b23b1eb28/dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz#sha256=8ca127253a0ca82a3d847148515f82ff2c504ed77a6385ec4f38c7f8e5360860
```

it returning **error** as

```
Collecting https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/62/aacb236d21fbd08148b1d517d58a9d80ea31bdcd386d26f21f8b23b1eb28/dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz#sha256=8ca127253a0ca82a3d847148515f82ff2c504ed77a6385ec4f38c7f8e5360860
  Using cached dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz (3.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-waso8gw6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\
    Complete output (74 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 10 2010
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      Failed to run MSBuild command:

        C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe

      to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

        Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.8.3752.0
        [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
        Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

        Build started 2/7/2020 12:53:19 PM.
        Project "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
        C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
        Done Building Project "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

        Build FAILED.

        "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
          C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.16.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

            0 Warning(s)
            1 Error(s)

        Time Elapsed 00:00:00.01


      Exit code: 1



    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/Charles/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-k3302dt_/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Charles\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-k3302dt_\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-waso8gw6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Im so lost, any response or suggestions will be appreciated so much. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have figured it out yourself, but I wanted to add some remarks on your installation methods:

```
pip install dlib
```

As there is only the `tar.gz` on pypi, it downloads that and then tries to run `setup.py` after installing the reuqirements

Therefore, you manually doing the `tar.gz`, extracting it and running `python setup.py install` is the same thing as the first command and also

```
python -m pip install  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/62/aacb236d21fbd08148b1d517d58a9d80ea31bdcd386d26f21f8b23b1eb28/dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz
```

Is doing the same in the end, trying to run `setup.py` to install.

In this case it involves the compilation of c/c++ code which requires for the right compiler/build tools to be installed which `pip` cannot take care of. It is not built for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by installing VS with C++.

Answer (score 1):

Please set your compiler path variable:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
```

and then do pip install dlib again. It should work. You might also want to check in usr/bin the right path to gcc.

Answer (score -1):

1. Python 3.6 (64 bit) has to be already installed.
2. Run Windows Prompt Command. 
   You can type on the search bar “CMD”.
   *Remember to click with right button of the mouse and then “Run it as administrator”, otherwise you might not have the permission to install the library.*
3. Type on the prompt command

*python -m pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/ce/f8a3cff33ac03a8219768f0694c5d703c8e037e6aba2e865f9bae22ed63c/dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=794994fa2c54e7776659fddb148363a5556468a6d5d46be8dad311722d54bfcf*
4. Once you see the message “Successfully installed dlib“, it means that the installation has been completed

Comment: hi there thank you for your response. i've tried your method and its not working, it returning error